# \import and \includegraphics with macros: Preserving local path at macro definition time

Tags: graphics, import

I have been banging my head on this problem for a few days, trying many combinations of `\def`, `\edef`, `\noexpand`, `\expandafter`, etc.

Say I have a module at `/tmp/module/` which contains `module.tex` and `image.png`.
In `module.tex` I define a macro which, among other things, uses `\includegraphics` to pull in the image within this submodule with a relative path:

```
% module.tex
\newcommand{\myQuizHeader}[1]{
  Quiz #1
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{image.png}
}
```

And then from my main document I do an `\import` or `\subimport`, and then try to use the `\myQuizHeader` macro:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
  \import{/tmp/module/}{module.tex}
  \myQuizHeader{27}
\end{document}
```

While import correctly prepends the module path in order to find files and images relative to the module while inside `module.tex`, those paths get removed when leaving the module, so the macros defined in that module don't work correctly anymore. When I call `\myQuizHeader{27}` from the main file the image is not found.

What is the correct way to solve this? I tried playing tricks with saving the `\Ginput@path` variable to a local variable within the module, but then I got into `\edef` and `\noexpand` hell.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you just prepend `/tmp/module/:` to TEXINPUTS environment variable (or the `\Ginput@path`) you don't need `\import` to do anything just `\includegraphics{image}` should find `image.png`