# \input and \import not working within macro

Tags: macros, input, import

I'm trying to include PDF+LaTeX figures exported from Inkscape in my document. Both .pdf_tex and .pdf files are inside the same path, nested within the project root. These two pieces of code work nicely:

```
\def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
\import{figs/}{myfig.pdf_tex}
```

or

```
\def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
\graphicspath{{figs/}}
\input{figs/myfig.pdf_tex}
```

I wanted to make a macro of these, so I tried:

```
\newcommand{\includepdflatexOne}[3][\linewidth]{
\def\svgwidth{{#1}}
\import{#2}{#3.pdf_tex}
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\includepdflatexTwo}[3][\linewidth]{
\def\svgwidth{#1}
\graphicspath{{#2}}
\input{#2#3.pdf_tex}
}
```

but calling either `\includepdflatexOne{figs/}{myfig}` or `\includepdflatexTwo{figs/}{myfig}` results in

```
! LaTeX Error: File `myfig.pdf_tex' not found.
```

Why doesn't LaTeX find the file when `\input` or `\import` are called from within a macro? I also tried `subimport`, but the same happened.

I believe my question may be related to [this (unanswered) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167656/import-and-includegraphics-with-macros-preserving-local-path-at-macro-definit), but reading it didn't help me.

Just in case, I'm using ShareLaTeX.

Comment: `\input` works the same way whether or not it is in a macro but it is hard to say why your file is not found just from these fragments. (setting graphicspath-per inclusion is rather odd but should work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\def\svgwidth{{#1}}
```

if `#1` is `\linewidth` (your default) will be

```
\def\svgwidth{{\linewidth}}
```

which will be an error.  You only want want set of braces.

Comment: @Marshall  hmm you accepted this but it surely gave a syntax error at the length setting not (initially) the file not found error?